# SQLite datetime conversion to timestamp

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I need to find data from previous 7 days. I have written the query which does work alright if the date is in timestamp format which is `2456735.5`, but it doesn't work when the date is in the below format.

```
Mon Mar 03 2014 14:20:27 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

The query is below:

```
select * from quiz 
  where  date(quiz_complete_date) <= date("now") 
  and  date(quiz_complete_date) >= date(date("now") , "-7 days")  
group by quiz_complete_date;
```

This query gets me results when the `quiz_complete_date` is in timestamp format but I am wondering why it doesn't work otherwise. Is there anyway I can convert it to timestamp so that I can get the results?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to use that date format in SQL.

You should always store days in one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).